# Custom error message in require() not showing up?

Tags: solidity, require

I've got Solidity v0.4.24

And I'm doing this:

```
require(false,"this is a test");
```

When I run `truffle test` I get the revert, but I cant see the error message.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't currently use web3 to inspect error messages thrown from `revert`. In the future it may be possible though, so adding these to your smart contract helps to future proof against this development.

You can follow the discussion at:
https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/pull/658