# Getting error message from require()

Tags: solidity, truffle, remix, parity, revert-opcode

I know that the latest Solidity supports error messages in require/revert (`require(stuff, "problem")`).

Are there any clients that can get this message? Will I be able to see it if I execute the transaction in Parity, or Truffle, or Remix? Will it be visible on Etherscan?

EDIT: a similar question has been asked before ([Custom error message in require() not showing up?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/50970/custom-error-message-in-require-not-showing-up)). That one was about web3 not displaying the message. I know web3 doesn't support it yet, my question was about which other clients (Parity, Remix, or, maybe, just plain RPC) support it, so I believe it's not a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remix supports it.

in a code i am working on for     `require(stuff..,"player doesn't exist");`
i get in the console the message:

```
Reason provided by the contract "player doesn't exist"
```

[image]

Comment: Do you know of any way to do this with golang and not using remix?

Answer (score 0):

The latest Truffle supports it, plus we can get and decode the transaction trace using the Parity's replay transaction feature.